# How to delete / just make disappear option "Check update availability from Windows update" in Windows 10

Tags: windows-update, windows-10

To put it as short as possible:

When you go to Windows 10 location

Start->Settings->Update

You can search for updates. This will search updates from wsus as it is supposed to with this domain joined computer.

How ever, below "search for updates" button there is a checkbox for "check update availability from microsoft update".

Checking this option will download drivers/updates from Microsoft Update instead of Wsus.

I would need to make this checkbox disappear, so users couldn't check this box accidentally or without knowing what they do, as it will cause some problems.

**I have already read and tested** this solution for the same problem:
[Is there a way to disable "check online for updates from windows update" in windows update settings?](https://serverfault.com/questions/680664/is-there-a-way-to-disable-check-online-for-updates-from-windows-update-in-wind)

How ever, enabling the group policy that prevents connection to microsoft update will also stop the device manager for finding updates, as all possible drivers can't be stored on the wsus server. This can cause problems with more exotic plug and play devices or when trying to fix a driver problem.

This is why I'm trying to find out, if it is possible to only make this checkbox "Check update availability from Microsoft Update" to disappear at the Settings->Update section, but still have the connection to Microsoft update work otherwise, when that is needed.